# Is there a way to create a message box without JS?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

Is there a way to create a message box with Yes / No buttons in a webform without the use of Javascript or System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox ?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use JavaScript or are you just trying to avoid using the `alert` function?

Comment: I am told not to use Js by my supervisor :'(

Comment: Is he aware ASP.NET probably uses some JavaScript anyway unless you've taken special measures. JavaScript is a much cleaner way of showing a message box!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of course - just create an appropriately styled panel with a couple of buttons; obviously you'll have to contend with postbacks so it won't be nearly as performant but definitely do-able. Something like:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="myDialogBox">
    <p>Are you sure you want to continue?</p>
    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnYes" Text="Yes" OnClick="btnYes_Click" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnNo" Text="Yes" OnClick="btnNo_Click" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

with the event handlers left for you to implement